# How the arr[] is sorted in a void method when it has no return value?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am new in java. This a sorting code where a void method used to sort values. The sort method doesn't return any values but in the main method if I print the main array I can see these values are sorted. I don't understand how it happens. I only call the sort method which is void and I don't print anything from void method and as it is void, it can't return anything. Then how the main method can get the sorted values?

```
public static void sort(int [] ar,int n){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
          int temp;
          if (ar[j]>ar[j+1]){
            temp= ar[j];
            ar[j]= ar[j+1];
            ar[j+1]= temp;
          }
        }

    }

}
```

```
public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter input here: ");

        int n= scan.nextInt();

        int arr[]= new int[n+2];
        System.out.println("Enter input here: ");
        for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
          arr[i]= scan.nextInt();
        }
         for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
         System.out.printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
        }
        sort(arr,n);

        System.out.println("\n");

         for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
         System.out.printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The array is sorted in-place.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) how array is passed into function